# My Kaminari links are not working with Rails, unless I reload the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

EDIT:
Basically it is because I am making the pagination links appear in a bootstrap class - col-xs-5 so everything appeared to the right of the page. When I commented it all out, the links worked fine but everything is in the center of the page now like normal non-Bootstrap content..what to do?

EDIT:
Is this a browser thing? I'm on a Macbook Pro OSX Yosemite, using the Safari browser.

---

Basically, if I select page 2, that URL is correctly shown in the browser URL field: localhost:3000/users/showtasksforuser?page=2, but the entries for page 2 are not rendered in place of page 1 unless I reload the page2 URL manually by pressing enter.

(As a sidenote, users/showtasksforuser works and users/showtasksforuser/?page=1 is not needed for the first page).

In users/showtasksforuser.html.erb:

```
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
                        </br></br>
                        <div style="text-align:center"><%= task.name %></div>
                    <% end %>


                    <%= paginate @tasks, :remote => true %>
```

In my Users controller:

```
def showtasksforuser
@tasks = Task.page(params[:page]).per(1)
end
```

In my Task model:

```
paginates_per 1
```

is the first line after the model declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not created a showtasksforuser.js.erb file.

```
<div id="taskList">
    <%= render "task_list"%>
</div>

<%= paginate @tasks, :remote => true %>
```

**_task_list.html.erb**

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    </br></br>
    <div style="text-align:center"><%= task.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

def showtasksforuser
    @tasks = Task.page(params[:page]).per(1)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
    end
end

**showtasksforuser.js.erb**

```
$("#taskList").html('<%= escape_javascript(render "task_list")%>')
```

I recommend changing the name of the action and the files to `show_tasks_for_user`

Comment: As in, everything is exactly how it was before. No new bugs.

Comment: The problem was with my bootstrap classes. When I commented them out temporarily, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. In my case, this works perfectly well:

```
<%= paginate @tasks %>
```

I just remove the `:remote => true` from `paginate`, and this makes all the default buttons from Kaminari works.